# Building Qt 5.2.1 from sources on Windows - OpenGL/angle error

Tags: qt, build

I am trying to build QT now for 2 days but it just doesn't work. This is what I did so far:

- getting source (qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1)
- installing perl, python, directx 9 sdk
- adding perl, python to path variable
- open cmd:

```
    CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

    set PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1source\qtbase\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1source\qtrepotools\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1source\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%

    set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2010 

    cd C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1source\

    configure -debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010 -confirm-license (also tried with -opengl desktop)

    nmake
```

And then I get this error message:

```
qplatformopenglcontext.cpp
c:\qtdev\qtbase-build\include\qtgui\../../../qtbase/src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h(55)
 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLES2/gl2.h': No such file or d
irectory
qopenglcontext.cpp
c:\qtdev\qtbase-build\include\qtgui\../../../qtbase/src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h(55)
 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLES2/gl2.h': No such file or d
irectory
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

the same like here: [QT_BUG](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28315) but this should be fixed in 5.1.0 so I guess I do something wrong but I don´t know what :( It´s driving me crazy! I tried several different confiure settings but always the same error.

Btw: I had the same error before I installed DirectX SDK, the only thing changed after installing was the warning after performing configure doesn't show anymore.

Do you have any clue how I can get this working?

Comment: find the folder with the gles subfolder and add to the include path?

Comment: i know the folder, but how can i add it to the include path? this is not about a qt application, i want to build the QT binaries myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install DirectX SDK.
Read more: https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36324

Comment: hey thanks for answering but i already did that (like i wrote) it didn´t change anything, I still get the error :(

Comment: Try to copy content of src\qtbase\include\QtANGLE
to Qt Include directory, it should fix it any way.
Also there is update Qt 5.3.0